# Android Studio : Error:"Could not create the Java Virtual Machine" when i ran my app

Tags: java, android, gradle, virtual

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1, i was following a video tutorial and i have made the excact same code as in the tutorial, but when i ran the app i have encountered this error :

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqcPr.png)

Even though i have set my gradle.properties to

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m`

And why is it giving me this message :

[setText Message in Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chiAZ.png)

Btw i am a newbie to Android Studio.

Comment: Did you download Java sdk? Is Java install in that path?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez Thank you that fixed my problem after i changed to a newer version of jdk.

Comment: `Why is it giving me this message` Read the message. That's why. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by downloading a newer version of JDK and going to :

File > Project Structure > JDK location

and changing the folder from

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55

to

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73